# React-Apollo: Specifying option fetchPolicy: "network-only" using withApollo doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I am just trying to set `fetchPolicy` as `network-only` when using it on a button click using `withApollo`. This is what my query looks like:

```
this.props.client.query({
  query: getStuff,
  variables,
  options: {fetchPolicy: "network-only"}
})
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

I tried it with a couple of different ways but nothing. What am I missing here?

I am using React-Apollo 1.4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to modify how you're passing in the `fetchPolicy` option. If you [look in the docs](http://dev.apollodata.com/core/apollo-client-api.html#ApolloClient.query), there is no `options` property on the options object passed to `query`. Here's the correct way to set the fetch policy:

```
this.props.client.query({
  query: getStuff,
  variables,
  fetchPolicy: "network-only",
})
```